# PHP Converting milliseconds to date fails for specific millisecond (1425318722000)

Tags: php, date, milliseconds

So I'm trying to convert milliseconds to date in PHP and I thought the script I had was working fine but getting odd behaviour for a specific millisecond value (1425318722000).

I've checked this across a few websites and all come back with a valid value...

Monday, March 2, 2015 5:52:02 PM GMT

Mon Mar 02 2015 17:52:02

Mon Mar 02 2015 17:52:02 GMT+0000 (GMT)

Mon, 02 Mar 2015 17:52:02 GMT

Any idea why this occurs, is it a PHP bug perhaps?

```
php -r "var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', 1425318721999/1000));"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-03-02 17:52:01"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}

php -r "var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', 1425318722000/1000));"
bool(false)

php -r "var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', 1425318722001/1000));"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-03-02 17:52:02"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}

php -r "var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', 1425318722002/1000));"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-03-02 17:52:02"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}

php -r "var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', 1425318722003/1000));"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-03-02 17:52:02"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}

php -r "var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', 1425318722004/1000));"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-03-02 17:52:02"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}

php -r "var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', 1425318722005/1000));"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2015-03-02 17:52:02"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking I should be doing something like php -r "var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U', round(1425318722001/1000)));"

Comment: Can `DateTime` store milliceconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the fact that you're using the `'U.u'` mask, but the `.u` is lost from the value when the result is all 0s after the decimal for that division

```
for($ms = 1425318721999; $ms <= 1425318722001; ++$ms) {
    var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf('%14.3f', $ms/1000)));
}
```

Will work, because you're using sprintf() to force those zeroes to be retained after the decimal point

```
for($ms = 1425318721999; $ms <= 1425318722001; ++$ms) {
    var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('U', floor($ms/1000)));
}
```

would also work, but you'd lose the milliseconds precision

By way of some explanation:

```
public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )
```

the `createFromFormat()` expects a string as the second argument, so PHP is loose casting the result of your division to a string, and a float value like `1425318722.000` will be cast to a string of `"1425318722"` with no decimal point or following zeroes, so it doesn't conform with the `U.u` mask which requires the decimal point and following digits

Comment: Just found out the same!

Comment: Thanks Mark, nice explanation...btw hope you don't mind copied your ZF certification badge idea

Comment: Just added a further bit of explanation about why the decimal point and digits matter and are being lost

Comment: And I'm all in favour of promoting certifications (though wondering if I should bother with sitting the ZCE 5.5 exam, or wait till there's a shiny new ZCE for PHP 7)

Comment: Yup, I know Sandy, cousins lived there. We played against Bedford school in Rugby, they didn't like loosing to a public school :D

Comment: I will probably resit for PHP 7 certification, always good to brush up on the new additions to the language as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76158/discussion-between-carlton-and-mark-baker).